# How can I reverse a nested list in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, reverse

I am trying to reverse a list similar to `(A,B,(C,(D,E)),F)` to return something like `(F,((E,D),C),B,A)` in haskell.
I know how to return a single list:

```
rev :: [a] -> [a]
rev [] = []
rev (x:xs) = (rev xs) ++ [x]
```

but how would I go about this for nested lists?

Comment: You need to provide your custom definition of a list because haskel `[]` can't hold different types and `["A", ["B"]]` means different types in the list.

Comment: @user1984 how do I do that?

Comment: Something like `data NestedList = NL [Either Int NestedList]`. Constructing such a list won't be as simple as `[1, [2,3]]`, though; you'd need `[Left 1, Right (NL ([Left 2, Left 3]))]`.

Comment: See also [`Forest`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.5.1/docs/Data-Graph.html#t:Forest).

Comment: @DanielWagner Thank you but I can not use any pre implementations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible implementation is as follows:

```hs
data Tree a = Leaf a | Node [Tree a] deriving (Eq, Show)

rev (Leaf x)  = Leaf x
rev (Node xs) = Node (go (reverse xs)) where
  go ((Leaf y):ys) = Leaf y: go ys
  go ((Node y):ys) = rev (Node y): go ys
  go []            = []
```

A short test:

```
λ> tree = Node [Leaf 'A', Leaf 'B', Node [Leaf 'C', Node [Leaf 'D', Leaf 'E']]]
λ> rev tree
Node [Node [Node [Leaf 'E',Leaf 'D'],Leaf 'C'],Leaf 'B',Leaf 'A']
```

As Daniel Wagner pointed out, this can be implemented much simpler and more elegant:

```hs
rev2 (Leaf x) = Leaf x
rev2 (Node xs) = Node (reverse (map rev2 xs))
```

Comment: `rev (Node xs) = Node (reverse (map rev xs))`?

Comment: Wow, thanks for pointing that out. I'm going to add it to the answer. @DanielWagner